Get of unique user count per day using LogQL
How do I get the unique user per day using LogQL
With the following I can get the number of access per userID, but not over time.
count by(userId) count_over_time({namespace=`myNamespace`} | pattern `<_>userId:"<userId"`)[$__interval])]

Is there a good example on the background that I can follow?

What do you mean by "but not over time"? If you'll change $__interval to 1d, you'd get result for over a last day. Is that not what you want?
